# How can I map 3000 geotagged photos?

Tags: leaflet, maps

What could be the best solution for this?

I'm looking for the simplest way to create an online map with 3000 photos in it. I'm looking for batch upload (say, upload all the photos in a folder). Should be a very simple map with photos in it.